# Testing fails when using defaultValues from react-hook-form and zod

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, react-hook-form, zod

I use react-hook-form, zod and react-testing-library.
I also use Controlled inputs and based on the react-hook-form I should use defaultValues to properly reset my form.
When submitting the form i get a TypeError, but I want a required_error. Thats why TEST 2 is failing.
When not including defaultValues TEST 3 fails.

When the form is empty I want the required Error and not the typeError. How can I do that with react-hook-forms defaultValues and zod

Here is the Link to Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-bhabha-kslrhv?file=/src/AddressForm.test.js